# Cast a column to a sortable data type using Linq to Entities(automatically if possible)

Tags: sorting, casting, linq-to-entities

When trying to apply sorting on a Linq to Entities column originally of type `Text` I get the following error:

```
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when 
using IS NULL or LIKE operator
```

I'm aware that is due to the column data type not being sortable and in plain SQL I can easily get around it by casting it to something sortable like so:

```
cast(ColumnName as varchar(MAX))
```

However I have no idea how to do this using Linq. Can anyone please help?

Ideally I'd want to auto-determine the column type at runtime and apply the appropriate casting prior to sorting.

Comment: FYI, "ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work" .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1cbe74b-062f-422f-9e83-0115ae5921e6/ntext-and-text-fields-problem-with-linq?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Answer (score 1):

You can imply the casting in Linq by converting the value as suggested in the link below:
[How can linq to sql be forced to convert ntext column into nvarchar(max) in the generated sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828452/how-can-linq-to-sql-be-forced-to-convert-ntext-column-into-nvarcharmax-in-the)

Or

You could create a `View` which explicitly selects all of the columns on the underlying table of the entity you've mapped and cast the value in the view.  You would then remap your entity to point to the view.

```
create view dbo.MyView
as

    select ID, cast(Value as varchar(max)) [Value] from dbo.MyTable 

go

select * from dbo.MyTable order by Value
```

However you would need to either map INSERT and UPDATE stored procedures on the entity or create INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE triggers on the view because of the following error restriction imposed on the view:

```
Update or insert of view or function 'dbo.MyView' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

Insert trigger example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyView_InsTrigger on dbo.MyTable
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Value)
    SELECT ID, Value FROM inserted

END
GO
```

Comment: Maybe the linked solution works in Linq to SQL, but not in Linq to Entities