# How can linq to sql be forced to convert ntext column into nvarchar(max) in the generated sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Below problem had me look for a solution for couple of hours. I finally found it and wanted to share so I can save other people spending time on it.

I have a query in linq to sql that needs to sort and group by on a column whose type is ntext. Sorting or grouping on ntext column causes **“The text, ntext and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.”** Before sorting or grouping takes place, the data needs to be casted into nvarchar. How can I instruct linq to sql to cast my ntext column into nvarchar(max) column?

Answer (score 5):

Calling **Convert.ToString("Value")** caused the column values to be casted from ntext to nvarchar(max) and resulting sql was **CONVERT(NVarChar(max),Value)**. Then sorting and grouping worked just fine.